# How to automatically accept Alerts with Appium -- permissions Android 6.0

Tags: android, permissions, appium, alerts

Environment:

- OS Windows 7
- Appium 1.4.16.1
- Android emulator 6.0

I need to accept any permission alerts(Android 6.0 -- sms,location and etc) automatically.

What I tried:

1. Use `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();`

   Result:

   `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html`
2. Set `capabilities`:

   `capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");`
   `capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", "true");`

   Result: it doesn't work

Comment: Can you try accepting the alert by like driver.findElemt way

Comment: I tried: 1) driver.findElement(MobileBy.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.Button'][2]")).click();
           2) driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")).click(); But these ways don't work also((

Answer (score 2):

It wont work in appium.If your alert contains 'ALLOW' button.Try to use below code:

```
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("ALLOW").click();
```

This will click on "ALLOW" button which means accepting the alert.

Comment: Standart Android system alert. Contains two buttons: DENY --- ALLOW

Comment: Ya that also will work in the same way.Try driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("ALLOW").click();

Answer (score 2):

It will definitely work for you.

```
DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give all the required permissions to the app before you launch the app. Below is the list of commands for required permissions. You can execute these commands through your Java code.

```
    adb -s yourDeviceSerialNumber shell pm grant your.app.packagename android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    adb -s yourDeviceSerialNumber shell pm grant your.app.packagename android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    adb -s yourDeviceSerialNumber shell pm grant your.app.packagename android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    adb -s yourDeviceSerialNumber shell pm grant your.app.packagename android.permission.CAMERA
    adb -s yourDeviceSerialNumber shell pm grant your.app.packagename android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
    adb -s yourDeviceSerialNumber shell pm grant your.app.packagename android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
```

Answer (score 1):

```
capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS, true);
```

It does work.

You can try it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `'autoGrantPermissions': 'true',` to your desired capabilities!

Please note! This will auto accept all the permissions where-ever applicable and is only valid for android system permissions. This is not applicable for app customized developed permissions.

Comment: In my case opening the camera application it asks for a popup with next button even though adding this capability it is not handling

Answer (score 0):

try adding capability: 
`'autoGrantPermissions': 'true',`

had the same issue, this solved it for me.